# gvim colors the same as is the terminal

Tags: vim, vimrc, gvim

Is there a command I can put in the `.vimrc` to make gvim look like vim's setup in the terminal?

Same back ground, syntax highlighting, colors, and font.

To add to my question, is there a may for gvim to follow vim's vimrc?  That is, there layouts and actions are identical?

Answer (score 0):

Options like this can be set into `.vimrc` file

```
colorscheme slate
set background=dark
syntax on
set ai

if has('gui_running')
    set guifont=Monospace\ 11
endif
```

The first sets a color scheme. Here you can try with slate, ron, or other themes. Secondly, you need to enable syntax highlighting.
Then, enable auto indent, and finally, set the font.

Answer (score 0):

Usually people want it the other way around, using (approximated) colors defined in a GVIM color scheme in the console, too.

It all depends on your *colorscheme*; it provides the attributes (like bold / italic), foreground and background colors for terminals, color terminals, and the GUI. Good color schemes provide similar definitions for all three. You can get your colorscheme's path from the `:scriptnames` output and check its contents.

For the font, just `:set guifont=...` in your `~/.gvimrc` and choose the same value as you have in your terminal emulator.

Comment: Note that if you have a 256 colour enabled terminal, you might get away with the same colours in both vim and gvim.

Comment: @Ingo Karkat there is nothing related to colorscheme in the scriptnames output.  How would it be labeled?

Comment: You recognize this by the `/colors/*.vim` in the path. If there's none, you're using the default colors, and you should then set one via `:colorscheme`.